# Laravel cache refresh without service impact

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I use [spatie's laravel-responsecache](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-responsecache) package in my Laravel application to cache massive API response couple times a day. The problem is that the application is used all the time and cache refresh causes service downtime if someone access to API while it's getting refreshed.

With current solution I call first `php artisan responsecache:clear` and run cache request right after that. I was just thinking if it's possible somehow to cache API response on background and overwrite old cache just when background caching is completed without any service downtime?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this using a custom cache profile class... I've not tried this; but I think it should work if you configure the 'useCacheNameSuffix' method to append a 'version' or 'generation' number to the end of the cache key. You'll need to persist this somewhere - within the cache should work.

When you want to regen the cache - you increment this cache key, generate a new cache and then persist the new cache key; various ways to do that - sinply as a magic querystring parameter or ideally a command line task?